# How do I configure Thunderbird Unity integration, particularly the monitoring of selected folders?

Tags: 11.10, unity, thunderbird

In ubuntu 11.04 I was using two thunderbird extensions :
- Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher Integration 
- Unity Launcher Integration

Since 11.10 it seems they are bundled with thunderbird.

But I miss a configuration feature that limit the folders which are monitored by the extensions.
I just want to monitor Inbox folders for new mails, not all of my folders...

Is there a way do to this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Thunderbird running select ***Edit -> Preferences***, in the dialogue box that opens up on the **General** tab simply select the option as shown below;

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's as easy as that on one of my ubuntu, but I can't find this option on my other Ubuntu. Need to check what's the difference.

Comment: You need to check what version of Thunderbird you are running - version 8 is the latest.

Comment: I have exactly the same version of all thunderbird package on both computer : thunderbird 8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
thunderbird-globalmenu 8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
thunderbird-gnome-support 8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
thunderbird-locale-fr 1:8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.11.10.1

Comment: I don't suppose there's a way of setting specific folders?