# Stop Thunderbird messaging menu from searching archive

Tags: unity, thunderbird, messaging-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure Thunderbird Unity integration, particularly the monitoring of selected folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84614/how-do-i-configure-thunderbird-unity-integration-particularly-the-monitoring-of)

The messaging menu tells me I've got new mail, but often that mail is in an archive directory or my drafts. Can I tweak the Thunderbird messaging menu in some way to tell it not to look for unread messages in Archive?

I wind up archiving a lot of unread messages. Without getting into the fact that I should probably just be throwing them straight in the Trash, is there a right way to tell Unity's launcher and message-menu indicator that it should only look for unread mail in my inboxes? It flags new mail in my archive folders as well as new drafts. I really don't want those flagged.

Comment: @jrg now if only there were an answer. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84614/how-do-i-configure-thunderbird-unity-integration-particularly-the-monitoring-of), which has already been answered.

(couldn't find out how to properly mark this question as duplicate...)

Comment: To mark it as a duplicate, you'd use the "close" option if you have it, otherwise the "flag" option.